# How to detect if a new collection has been created?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I use collection hooks to see if a new document has been inserted into a collection or if an existing one has been modified.

But is there any way to detect (within Meteor) if I've created a new collection or removed a collection?

I'm thinking of an interval using https://github.com/dburles/mongo-collection-instances:

`Mongo.Collection.getAll() // returns a list of all collections`

Is there any better way than this? Like a collection created/deleted event?

Answer (score 1):

How to detect if a new collection has been created?

Terminal Command For list Collections in Mongodb:

show collections 
    or 
show tables

Comment: I meant from within Meteor itself.